# JSON array of strings foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, react-native

Example JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Size",
  "options": [
    "S",
    "M",
    "L"
  ]
}
```

I do not understand why `options` is parsed as a string like `SML` and foreach does not work

**SOLVED:**

Instead of doing a foreach I used a for

```
const jsonData = '{"name": "Size","options": ["S","M","L"]}'
const data = JSON.parse(jsonData)

// Foreach not be used in array of strings, this was the error
//data.options.forEach((option) => {
//
//})

// For works fine
for (const i = 0; i < data.options.length; i++) {
  const option = data.options[i]
}
```

Comment: show us your code here, so we know where the error..

Comment: I don't see an issue!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine:

```
var json = `{
  "name": "Size",
  "options": [
    "S",
    "M",
    "L"
  ]
}`;

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.options);
```

See [**DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/hujegov/edit?html,js,console,output).

You don't show how you parse it, how you access the `obj.options` array, what you get and what you expect. It's impossible to tell you what's wrong with your code that you don't show. The JSON is fine and I showed you the correct way to parse it that works as expected.